# Java generics question on designing the class

Tags: java, generics

I am stuck and unsure how to properly check / ensure that my B is operating on valid types found in the collection.

OperateAll should be generic, accepts a collection of objects, and only uses Bs that are of the type of the objects found in the collection.

```
public interface B<T> {
    public boolean operate(T t);
}

public class OperateAll<T> implements B<T> {
    private Collection<T> collection;

    public OperateAll(Collection<T> collection) {
        this.collection = collection;
    }

   //I need to ensure T is of type B<T>, so I can do the described if statement
    public boolean operate(T t) {
        if (t == null) {
            return false;
        }

        for (T item : reference) {
           // if !t.operate(item) return false; 
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Clarification on the problem:
I need do something like this:

```
Collection<Integer> collection = new LinkedList<>();
Integer[] numbers = new Integer[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
Collections.addAll(collection, numbers);
B<Integer> op = new OperateAll<>(collection);
B<Integer> validateNumber = new ValidNumber<>();
//if B<String> validateNumber, this should not be allowed as an argument.
op.operate(validateNumber);
```

This way, validateNumber can check if it can operate on all the items in the collection in op.

Comment: so your B OperateAll operates only on B?

Comment: You may indeed be overthinking this. From what you have shown so far, I think you just want to make a static helper method `static <T> boolean operateAll(clazz: Class<? extends T>, operator: B<T>, input: Collection<?>)` that runs the relevant entries in `input` through `operator.operate`.  (You have to pass in the class, because generics are erased at runtime so you cannot do `instanceof` checks without this "evidence".)

Comment: Yes njzk2, basically the type declared in B should also be the type in the collection. But I am unsure how to test the answer given by Sweeper.

Comment: @Thilo it's java question, please use java syntax, put types before names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you don't need the constraint on `T`. Instead, `OperateAll` should implement `B<B<T>>`, not `B<T>`:

```
class OperateAll<T> implements B<B<T>> {
    private Collection<T> collection;

    public OperateAll(Collection<T> collection) {
        this.collection = collection;
    }

    public boolean operate(B<T> t) {
        if (t == null) {
            return false;
        }

        for (T item : collection) {
            if (!t.operate(item)) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

This makes code like this possible:

```
Collection<Integer> collection = new LinkedList<>();
Integer[] numbers = new Integer[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
Collections.addAll(collection, numbers);
// note the type of op
B<B<Integer>> op = new OperateAll<>(collection);
B<Integer> validateNumber = x -> x > 3;
op.operate(validateNumber);
B<String> validateString = x -> x.length() > 3;
op.operate(validateString); // error
```

Comment: Yes thank you, do you know how I can test this?                                   Collection<Integer> collection = new LinkedList<>();
B<Integer> pred = new AcceptsAllOf<>(collection);                                          //can't infer the argument types

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, Sweeper. It still can't infer the type?

Comment: @NoobieProgrammer Actually, the more I look at your code the more I don't understand what you are trying to do. Can you show your ultimate aim?

Comment: @NoobieProgrammer your clarification helped. Now I understand what you want. I've posted an answer.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
public class OperateAll<T> implements B<B<T>> {
    private final Collection<? extends T> collection;

    // Bounded wildcard is used here because this class only reads from collection
    public OperateAll(Collection<? extends T> collection) {
        this.collection = collection;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean operate(B<T> t) {
        return t != null && collection.stream().allMatch(t::operate);
    }
}
```

---

Note: if you want you can implement `operate` in an imperative way as well:

```
@Override
public boolean operate(B<T> t) {
    if (t == null) return false;
    for (T elm : collection)
        if (!t.operate(elm)) return false;
    return true;
}
```

---

Note 2: I suggest using `Predicate` instead of `B`.

Comment: May I ask how you how knew to do                                                       implements B<B<T>>?

Comment: @NoobieProgrammer I looked at `public boolean operate(B<T> t)` method signature and see that it accepts `B<T>`, so I put `B<T>` as the type parameter of `B` in `implements` clause.